# tkinter python program structure

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to python programming, and I have a bit of trouble with the program structure:
When I make my GUI in the main python part then the code works:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.overrideredirect(True)
root.geometry("800x480")

def cb_Gebruiker():
    btnUser["text"]= "changed"

btnUser = tk.Button(root, text="User",command = cb_Gebruiker)
btnUser.place(x=1,y=1,width="300",height="73")


root.mainloop()
```

When I make my GUI in a function, the btn variable is local, so this doesn't work

```
def MakeBtn():
    btnUser = tk.Button(root, text="User",command = cb_Gebruiker)
    btnUser.place(x=1,y=1,width="300",height="73")

def cb_Gebruiker():
    btnUser["text"]= "changed"

MakeBtn()


root.mainloop()
```

Now I have a program that's rather large and I want my GUI in a separate file, but then I can't access my GUI components...
And I can't seem to be able to find a tutorial on how to structure a program (python has to many possibilities: script, module, object oriented,..)

How do I solve this?

Comment: ***"want my GUI in a separate file ... possibilities: `script`, `module`, `object oriented`"***: You need all of them, read [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17470842/7414759)

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `lambda` to delay the call to the command with a parameter.

```
def MakeBtn():
    btnUser = tk.Button(root, text="User", command = lambda: cb_Gebruiker(btnUser))
    btnUser.place(x=1, y=1, width="300", height="73")

def cb_Gebruiker(btnUser):
    btnUser["text"] = "changed"

MakeBtn()


root.mainloop()
```